# Using AngularJS to consume REST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest, flask

I've made a REST api using Flask which gives a JSON response on http://localhost:5000/api/person giving the id,names and phone numbers of all the people in a SQLite database. http://localhost:5000/api/person/Name_of_person gives the JSON response corresponding to a person's name. I want to use AngularJS to consume the API so that I can output the names of all the people along with their phone numbers.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<ul>

  <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
    {{ x.id }} + ', ' + {{x.name }} + ',' + {{x.phone}}
  </li>

</ul>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://localhost:5000/api/person").then(function (response) {
  $scope.myData = response.data.objects;
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Contents of http://localhost:5000/api/person**

```
{
  "num_results": 5, 
  "objects": [
{
  "id": 24, 
  "name": "Name2", 
  "phone": "9999192938"
}, 
{
  "id": 23, 
  "name": "Name3", 
  "phone": "9999192938"
}, 
{
  "id": null, 
  "name": "Name4", 
  "phone": "9999192938"
}, 
{
  "id": 21, 
  "name": "Name5", 
  "phone": "9999192938"
}, 
{
  "id": null, 
  "name": "Name6", 
  "phone": "9999192938"
}
  ], 
  "page": 1, 
  "total_pages": 1
}
```

I am pretty sure my syntax is correct but I am getting no output for index.html. Can anyone please explain where I am going wrong? Is it maybe because it is on a local server and is unable to retrieve the data?

Comment: I would start by reading the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), in this case ng-repeat should do the trick for you.

Comment: @Jax I'm having problems running the application. If I have my REST api running on localhost:5000, can I just open the index.html page from a browser to view the correct output ?

Comment: is `output.js` a controller defined in your angular app? Also note that you are assigning the data from your api to `$scope.greeting` but in your view you call `{{Person.id}}`, where Person is not defined.

Comment: @Jax I've edited the question to rectify some mistakes I had made before, but it is still not working. Am I still wrong somewhere?

Comment: @Jax for some reason I am unable to solve this issue - I have put some more detail in the question. If you can help me in any way, I would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Is index.html also being served on localhost:5000? If it's a different host or port number, it may be you are encountering a CORS error in the browser if the server doesn't specifically enable it in the response headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please test the api by REST client, if the API returns proper result.
2. If you are having problem in running the application, please test using firefox browser. For chrome you need to serve the index.html through any server as it blocks file:/// protocol and needs http:// to run properly.
3. Make sure your API supports CORS. You have to set it in API end (see Flask docs) or else you can use CORS plugin for chrome.
4. If still problem persists there might be any logical/syntactical error. Please paste/share screenshot of your browser console.